# Putting diagonal in an mxn matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, initialization, diagonal

I'm trying to construct the 2nd order operator matrix in matlab for an mxn matrix (n-2)xn more precisely.

I looked up diag but it only makes a square matrix. Just wondering for ideas.

Again, to reiterate,

```
D = diag(-2*ones(1,n-1),0)
```

will return -2 on the main diagonal but an mxn matrix does not have a main diagonal.

Comment: Can you provide an example output please

Comment: You can just pad the square matrix: `padarray(D, [0 2], 0, 'post')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html):

```
>> n = 6; m = n-2;
>> D = full(spdiags(-2*ones(m,1),0,m,n))
D =
    -2     0     0     0     0     0
     0    -2     0     0     0     0
     0     0    -2     0     0     0
     0     0     0    -2     0     0
```

Or just use [`eye`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html):

```
D = -2*eye(m,n)
```

Perhaps you want to combine several diagonals:

```
>> B = [ones(m,1) -2*ones(m,1) ones(m,1)];
>> D = full(spdiags(B,0:2,n-2,n))
D =
     1    -2     1     0     0     0
     0     1    -2     1     0     0
     0     0     1    -2     1     0
     0     0     0     1    -2     1
```